# IE vs Chrome - Difference in Icon Font Sizing

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, webkit

I'm using an icon font (from IcoMoon). I'm applying the icons as befores to my other elements.

The CSS applied to them is something like:

```
/** applied first */
.my-element:before {
    font-family: icomoon;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/** elsewhere */
.my-element:before {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

If I look at the actual font-size reported in Inspect Element for the before, it reports 21px, when logically I would expect 30px. Firefox appears to do the same. In IE, I get what I expect: 30px (20px * 1.5).

I have another where the second value is 2em, and Chrome gets 28px. IE gets the expected 40px.

Even expanding the thing to see what components go in to calculating the final font-size value only shows those two.

I thought maybe the parent element was getting calculated in, so I set it to 0px, and it didn't affect the before. I'm stumped.

Which browser is correct? I generally assume IE is wrong, but if it is, there must be some rule that I'm unaware of. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you duplicate this is a jsFiddle? `em`s inherit from the parent element. From what you've described it sounds like there may be another CSS selector at play.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't because CORS blocks the font load, unless someone knows of either a test icon font I can use or knows something like JSFiddle which'll let me upload a file with it.

Comment: Though, upon you saying that, it made me realize that's probably the case, and indeed it was. The parent font size was set to 14px, and 14px * 1.5 is 21px, so that makes sense. Now it looks like IE was in the wrong. It seems IE did take both in to account, which is odd now that I think about it properly. Going to see if I can't put together a basic JSFiddle to compare.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xdzzrvb1/2/ It is a quirk with IE (using 11). It seems like IE multiplies the pixel font size with the em font size, even though the em font size should have overridden the pixel font size and used the parent's as the multiplier. Has nothing to do with using an icon.